# Has anybody ever tried to eat a Xenomorph?

Tags: alien-franchise

Has anybody or *anything* ever tried to eat a Xenomorph from the *Alien* franchise? (Obviously the acid blood would need to be drained/neutralized.) If so, when have we seen this happen?

Comment: No they haven't. And since the Alien is silicon-based, I'd expect it to taste *awful*

Comment: People eat cockroaches and jellyfish though. There has to be some meat somewhere on it, right?

Comment: Is this on-topic here, or should this go to [Seasoned SE](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Seanoseanohay That's not the issue. Cockroaches and jellyfish are still carbon-based life (I'm pretty sure roach shells are carbon-based, but I don't care to Google an answer); unless you've been to some very wild parties, everything you've ever eaten has been some configuration of carbon atoms and water. You could probably eat a silicon-based steak, but I doubt you could derive any nutrition from it

Comment: @MattGutting - Can you read Elvish?

Comment: Like I can read Greek, i.e. I can sound it out

Comment: Silicon tends to exist in three forms - glass, rock, or with hydrogen in long chains that mimic proteins and other living molecules. However, this material is basically a synthetic rubber.
In less technical terms, the "meat" on a silicon based lifeform would tend to be like Silly Putty in texture.

Comment: They have natural predators, so yes.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would help, but are you looking for only humans? Perhaps some *Aliens vs. Predators* material (books, comics) might contain some mention of eating an Xeno for some ritual. I dunno if it does exist, but it opens up possibilities.

Comment: I wonder what Excalbians or Horta taste like.

Comment: @T-1000s-Son I'm gonna guess chicken

Comment: @CreationEdge - Yes, I think that would be fine. I am wondering if they have been eaten...As yasskier says, "They have natural predators...".

Comment: @T-1000'sSon - Like hot rocks.